# Pyhton. ¿Cómo cambiar líneas en archivo de texto conservando la línea original?

Tags: python, funciones

Basado en esta [información](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/Python/3843-Reemplazar-una-linea-de-un-archivo.html), modifiqué la función, para que cambie cada línea del contenido de un archivo de texto a minúsculas y reemplace los espacios por guiones.

```
def modificar(archivo, buscar, reemplazar):
with open(archivo, "r") as fichero:
    lines = (line.lower().replace(' ', '-') for line in fichero)
    new_line = [reemplazar if line==buscar else line for line in lines]
    
with open(archivo, "a") as fichero:
    fichero.write("\n".join(new_line) + '\n')

fichero.close()       #Uso modificar("prueba.txt", "", "")
```

El código funciona generando el cambio de las líneas como esperaba, así:

```
Primera Línea de Texto a Modificar
Segunda Línea de Texto a Modificar
Tercera Línea de Texto a Modificar

primera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar

segunda-línea-de-texto-a-modificar

tercera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar
```

He intentado modificar los bucles 'for' en la función 'modificar' de manera que el resultado final de la función sea: la línea original, bajo ella la línea modificada, para todas las líneas del contenido así:

```
Primera Línea de Texto a Modificar
primera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar

Segunda Línea de Texto a Modificar
segunda-línea-de-texto-a-modificar

Tercera Línea de Texto a Modificar
tercera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar
```

**Observaciones**: aunque cuando se utiliza 'with' para abrir archivos de texto esta implícito el cierre del archivo, incluí 'fichero.close()' porque en alguna prueba en busca del resultado final obtuve un archivo "prueba.txt" de unos 268mb hasta que pude parar el proceso.

Aunque la función 'modificar' que yo he reescrito hace los cambios, ¿cómo puedo hacer para obtener el resultado final?

Gracias de antemano por la colaboración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas solamente es producir la siguiente salida:

```
Primera Línea de Texto a Modificar
primera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar
```

Lo que podrías hacer, por ejemplo, entre tantas maneras, es usar las dos listas, tanto origen como destino, entendiendo que ambas tienen la misma cantidad de elementos y hacer uso de la función [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip). De esta manera puedes iterar sobre las dos listas.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Leer el fichero y eliminar los saltos de línea (\n)
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    new_lines = [line.lower().replace(' ', '-') for line in lines]

for line in zip(lines, new_lines):
    print(line)
```

Si imprimimos c/u de las líneas de la iteración tendrás las siguientes tuplas:

```
('Primera Línea de Texto a Modificar', 'primera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar')
('Segunda Línea de Texto a Modificar', 'segunda-línea-de-texto-a-modificar')
('Tercera Línea de Texto a Modificar', 'tercera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar')
```

Por lo qué, si accedes a c/u de los elementos de la tupla e imprimimos como ejemplo:

```
for line in zip(lines, new_lines):
    print(line[0], '\n', line[1])
```

Tendrás el siguiente resultado:

```
Primera Línea de Texto a Modificar 
 primera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar
Segunda Línea de Texto a Modificar 
 segunda-línea-de-texto-a-modificar
Tercera Línea de Texto a Modificar 
 tercera-línea-de-texto-a-modificar
```

Y si tienes muchos elementos y no quieres generar una nueva lista y solo quieres iterar la primera podrías:

```
for line in lines:
    print(line, '\n', line.lower().replace(' ', '-'))
```

A partir de esto podrás almacenar en el fichero lo que necesites.

**EDITO**

Para escribir en un fichero, puedes usar de igual forma `with open` pero debes cambiar el filehandle de `r` (lectura) a `w` (escritura) o `a` (anexar o añadir).

```
with open('result_file.txt', 'a') as file:
    for line in zip(lines, new_lines):
        file.write(f"{line[0]}\n{line[1]}\n")
```

Ten cuidado de no sobreescribir el mismo fichero.

Ejemplo gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @Adrian, he tratado de implementar tu respuesta, pero no me aclaro. Me escribe en el archivo `'file.txt'` `NoneNoneNone`. Ahora, los `print()` van muy bien en el IDLE de Python, pero no me escriben el archivo `'file.txt'`.

Comment: Hola. `file.txt` sería solamente un ejemplo, entiendo que en ese fichero tienes en una linea "Primera Línea de Texto a Modificar", en otra línea "Segunda Línea de Texto a Modificar" y así sucesivamente. De esta manera podrá cargar el contenido de ese fichero y almacenar cada línea en la lista. Luego para escribir en el fichero tienes que cambiar en with open de `r` (lectura) a `w` (escritura) (sobreescribe el fichero) o 'a' (añadir) para cambiar el modo de manejar ese fichero.

Comment: Te coloco una imagen.

Comment: Gracias @Adrian, modificando el `file.write(f"{line[0]}\n{line[1]}\n" + "\n")` he logrado el resultado final esperado y, he aclarado mis conceptos sobre el bucle `for`.

Comment: Para eso estamos. Me alegro haber sido de ayuda.